# React-Native-Share - [Error: User did not share]

Tags: react-native, image, base64, react-native-share

I'm having trouble with sharing email.
I'm trying to share email with URL. It opens the Gmail form and fills all the data but when I'm clicking on `send` button It shows an error `[Error: User did not share]`.

Code:

```
let imagePath = null;

                RNFetchBlob.config({
                    fileCache: true
                })
                    .fetch("GET", imagesUrls[0])
                    .then(resp => {
                        imagePath = resp.path();
                        return resp.readFile("base64");
                    })
                    .then(async (base64Data) => {
                        var imageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64' + base64Data;

                        let shareImage = {
                            subject: `Shared Job from Group ${groupID}`,
                            email: shareEmail,
                            message: `Group ID ${groupID} | License Number: ${data.LicenseNumber}\n 
    Model: ${data.Manufacturer} ${data.Model} ${data.ProductionYear}\n
    Images:`,
                            url: imageUrl,
                            // urls: [imageUrl, imageUrl]

                        };

                        const shareResponse = await Share.open(shareImage)
                            .then((res) => {
                                console.log(res);
                            }).catch((err) => {
                                err & console.log(err);
                            })

                        // return fs.unlink(imagePath)
                    })
```

Form:
[image: Screenshot]

After clicking on the `blue share button` It sends an error to the console and brings me back to my app.